# How do I properly dynamically set variable names in a for loop?

Tags: javascript

Here is the code I have right now:

```
var ids = ["games", "lkarma", "ckarma", "twitter", "ram", "monitors"];
for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
  ids[i] = parseInt(document.getElementById(ids[i]).value, 10);
}
```

What I want it to do is set the variable `games` to the element with the id `games`, but this code just returns undefined for each variable.

Comment: is this happening in a dom-ready state?

Comment: take off the value and parseInt and store just the element reference.

Comment: You don't have a variable called `games`. Do you also realise that this code will only be useable once, due to you replacing the values in the array?

Comment: In is impossible for the index to be undefined since parseInt() does not return undefined.

Comment: Sorry, I think you misunderstood what I'm trying to do. I want a variable called `games` to be made, and be equal to the value of the element with the id `games`. I'm not trying to modify the actual array.

Comment: create a demo in jsfiddle.net that replicates problem. Also, since you are now overwriting the exisitng array values, givemore detailed explanation of goals

Comment: Ok, [here is the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uq5Wg/)

Comment: To technically answer the question: You could use the window object, but please please please do not do it this way, dynamic variable names are a very bad idea!  window[ids[i]] = parseInt(...);

Comment: So there is no way to do it apart from using `window`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `window` object:

```
var ids = ["games", "lkarma", "ckarma", "twitter", "ram", "monitors"];

for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
    window[ids[i]] = i;
}

console.log(games);
console.log(lkarma);
console.log(ckarma);
// ...
```

Comment: @NatZimmermann Ah, okay, I didn't see that. You can use `eval` tho, but that's even worse. Anyway, good luck with that :)

Comment: Thanks, looks like I'll just have to use this for the time being.

Comment: @NatZimmermann Welcome, you might be better to add something like `_` or `$` to the beginning of the `id`s if you think there might conflict with other variables also ...

Answer (score 0):

I think you want a custom object that stores your data. You can use your current ID array to create this. Something like this:

```
var ids = ["games", "lkarma", "ckarma", "twitter", "ram", "monitors"];

var myData = {};

for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
    var id = ids[i];
    myData[id] = parseInt(document.getElementById(id).value, 10);
}
```

You can then use it like so:

```
var games = myData["games"];
```

or

```
var games = myData.games;
```

[Here is a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/5tHNt/)

Comment: This doesn't work for me, it still says that the variable `games` is undefined.

Comment: I have posted a demo link... it works fine. How are you trying to access `games`?

Comment: @NatZimmermann: yeah... you don't have any HTML elements, obviously it wont be able to find them. Also, you have kept the same bad code, try it with mine!

Comment: Ok, I've added them, stupid oversight by me, but it still isn't working... http://jsfiddle.net/uq5Wg/3/